# Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice'

Tags: nfc

I have actually a USB Device plug on my computer.
This device allow me to read NFC but when I'm putting my NFC to be red the navigator (Chrome) returned me this error message :

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice': The requested interface implements a protected class.

My code is the next one :

```
var usbd = {};
let device;
let deviceEndpoint = 0x02;

let powerUpDevice = new Uint8Array([0x62,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00, 0x00]).buffer;
let getCardUID = new Uint8Array([0xff,0xca,0x00,0x00,0x04]).buffer;

(function() {
    'use strict';

    usbd.authorize = function(){
        navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x072f }] })
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                device = selectedDevice;
                console.log(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber);
                console.log(device.manufacturerName);
                console.log(device.productName);
                console.log(device);
                return device.open()
                    .then(() => {
                        if (device.configuration === null) {
                            return device.selectConfiguration(1);
                        }
                    });
            })
            .then(() => device.claimInterface(0))
            .then(() => device.transferOut(deviceEndpoint, powerUpDevice)
                .then(transferResult => {
                    console.log(transferResult);
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    device.close();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            );

    };

    usbd.getDevice = function(){
        return navigator.usb.getDevices().then(devices => {
            return devices.map(device => new usbd.device(device));
        });
    };

    usbd.device = function(device) {
        this.device_ = device;
    };

    usbd.getTagUID = function(){
        device = this.getDevice();

        device
            .then(device => {
                device[0].device_.open()
                    .then(() => device[0].device_.claimInterface(0))
                    .then(() => device[0].device_.transferOut(deviceEndpoint, getCardUID)
                        .then(transferResult => {
                            console.log(transferResult);
                        }, error => {
                            console.log(error);
                            device[0].device_.close();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                    )
                    .then(() => device[0].device_.claimInterface(0))
                    .then(() => device[0].device_.transferIn(deviceEndpoint, 16)
                        .then(USBInTransferResult => {
                            if (USBInTransferResult.data) {
                                console.log(USBInTransferResult.data.getUint32(0));
                            }
                        }, error => {
                            console.log(error);
                            device[0].device_.close();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                    );
            });
    };

    $('#connect').click(function(){
        usbd.authorize();
    });

    $('#readCard').click(function(){
        usbd.getTagUID();
    });

})();
```

How can I do to read my NFC on my website ?

Comment: You need to provide more details and code of what you are trying to do so that people can help.

Comment: I just added the code, sorry for missing

Comment: I guess this is on Windows. If so, the USB device likely implements a device class, which is exclusively claimed by Windows. Unlike on Linux and macOS, it cannot be accessed using general purpose USB APIs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Codo
Do you know how I can read the information from my USB NFC reader ?

Comment: Is it on Windows? If so, what USB NFC reader are you using? What kind of NFC information do you intend to read? What programming languages are you familiar with?

Comment: It is on Windows
I'm using a NFC reader from ShopNFC (ACR1252)
I want that my window can read the UID
I'm familiar with Javascript

Comment: I'm not familiar with Javascript options for NFC. You could try this node package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nfc-pcsc

Comment: I wanted to do it in Javascript vanilla  but thanks for the tips